# Get an image from php code to iOS app

Tags: php, ios, image

I am making an app where users need to enter their Name and it'll return their info about them. It works so far and all the info is getting returned. Now, I want add pictures that are uploaded on my server, that are all uploaded the same way like:

> mywebsite.com/images/users/charles.jpg

Depending on the name, so every user has it's own name. So for John it'll be:

> mywebsite.com/images/users/john.jpg

I want to get this: `mywebsite.com/images/users/{$name}.jpg`, because all the names they enter are returned like $name. That will come in the `php` file like this:

```
$image = 'http://mywebsite.com/images/users/{$name}.jpg'
```

Then I want to get that in an image field in the size of 160x160. I'm not that advanced with `xcode` and `obj-c`, I'm just experimenting.

This is how I want it to look:

[image: Example Design]

Would a framework suffice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this to fetch the image:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://mywebsite.com/images/users/Charles.jpg"];
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 yourImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

You can use this quickly to test it is working. BUT NSData:dataWithContentsOfURL is synchronous, so you MUST make the code asynchronous by wrapping the code in a call to dispatch_asyn on the main thread for example.

You could get it working synchronously first as a proof of concept, then do additional research on synchronous/asynchronous issues and the use of dispatch_aync etc. and ask follow up questions if necessary.

Alternatively you could also download the image using NSURLConnection or NSURLSession (which wouldn't require the use of dispatch_asyn) but using that is more involved, but it gives more flexibility if you need to deal with more complex network situations such as error situation,redirects, authentication challenges etc.

Comment: Uhm, and how can I get it to grab the image from the php file? with $image = 'http://mywebsite.com/images/users/{$name}.jpg'

Comment: That's an entirely different question, nothing to do with iOS. You should split your question into two, you shouldn't mix totally different issues in one question.

Comment: Well, it's in my question and its the main question.. I want to get these images by each person (around 50 persons..) dynamically on the UI

Answer (score 0):

**Functions**

```
- (void)downloadPicture :(NSString *) url{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        UIImage *image = [self getPicture:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (image!=nil)
                ImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                [ImageView setImage:image];
                [ImageCell.contentView addSubview:ImageView];
            }

        });
    });
}


- (UIImage *)getPicture:(NSURL *)pictureURL {    
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pictureURL];
    image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    return image;
}
```

**Execution**

```
[self downloadPicture :@"mywebsite.com/images/users/charles.jpg"];
```

Answer (score -1):

This is just one way to do it asynchronously. You should do what makes sense for you.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

     NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebsite.com/images/users/%@.jpg", name];

     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

};
```

Obviously you will have to get that "name" parameter in there somehow.